# php mysql foearch with the same value from email to users

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

i have this on my mysql database

```
email have 5 value
user have 15 value
```

how can i loop the email with something like this

```
email          user
ya1@yahoo.com  user1
ya2@yahoo.com  user2
ya3@yahoo.com  user3
ya4@yahoo.com  user4
ya5@yahoo.com  user5
ya1@yahoo.com  user6
ya2@yahoo.com  user7
ya3@yahoo.com  user8
--------------------
and so on....
```

using the php foreach...
something like when the users loop the email value will loop also and when it reach the end of the value of the email the email will start again to the first ya1@yahoo.com

is it possible to work on this on foreach or do it as a while?

Comment: 2 users have the same email? Odd.. shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: Are you trying to produce every permutation of user and email here? What you're trying to do doesn't make any sense!

Comment: im sorry email and user was just example.... sorry if i did not make it clear... let me say i have 5 fruits which are `orange,apple,grapes,banana,kiwii` then i have `users` in the database record 15, it will loop to every users... `post of MR. NomikOS` below Answers is a perfect sample thank you mr. NomikOS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$e = array('email1', 'email2' /* , more email */);
$u = array('user1', 'user2', 'user3' /* , more users */);

$total_e = count($e);
$total_u = count($u);
$total   = $total_e * $total_u;

$counting_e  = 0;
$counting_u  = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i ++ )
{
    echo nl2br($e[$counting_e ++] . " => " . $u[$counting_u ++] . "\n");

    if ($counting_e == $total_e)
        $counting_e = 0;
    if ($counting_u == $total_u)
        $counting_u = 0;
}
```

Test: http://codepad.org/R5PpAKQW

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array();
$i=0;
foreach($users as $user){
if(isset($email[$i])){
$data[$email[$i]] = $user;
}
else{
$i=0;
$data[$email[$i]] = $user;

}
$i++;
}
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$j=0;
for ($i=0;$i<count($users);$i++){
    if (count($email)<$j+1)
        $j=0;
    else
        $j++;
echo $users[$i].' has email: '.$email[$j];
}
```